# How to force or create a POST request from Code on Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

As a learning exercise to understand Node.JS and express.js I am writing a very simple application that handle users creation, deletion and sessions.

This is the code when a user deletes his profile:

```
app.del ('/users/:name', loadUser, restrictUserToSelf, function ( req, res, next ) {

connection.query (
        'DELETE FROM test_table WHERE User = ? ',
        [req.user.User],
        function ( err ) {
    if (err) {
                throw err;
    }
            console.log ( 'User deleted:'+req.user.User );
        });
    res.redirect('/users'); // Replace this line with POST to destroy the session
});
```

This code is working fine. I want to add a line to destroy the session after the user is deleted, however I already have a code that perform that work when the user log out

```
app.del ('/session', function ( req, res, next ) {
req.session.destroy();
res.redirect ('/users');
});
```

So in my mind all I have to do is force a POST to /session and change the _method to DELETE with Method Override.

I have look on Goggle but could not find how do I force that post and how do I change the _method from the code?
Can you guys help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why don't you call the `req.session.destroy()` before your `res.redirect('/users')` ? I think that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: You are right that this may be the simpler solution for this case. I an trying lo look ahead and assuming that on a real application I will need to do much more work than a simple req.session.destroy(), and even I could have the code duplicated may not be the best practice. That is why I was looking for a way to have the session closure on a single place and reusing everytime I need (user logout, timeout, etc...)

Comment: Well, to avoid code duplication just extract the destroying of session to it's own function. I think that if you want to redirect the POST request to the del function and change the http method on the fly, it just creates indirection to your code and makes things messy. I would prefer to keep things simple and extract the code to it's own function.